# Need help with the range of $n$ in this marginal PMF question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question came from MITx's 6.431x.

> Let $N$ be a positive integer random variable with PMF of the form

> $$P_N(n)=\frac{1}{2}\times n\times2^{-n}, n=1,2....$$

> Once we see the numerical value of $N$, we then draw a random variable $K$ whose conditional PMF is uniform on the set $\{1,2...,2n\}$.
> Find the marginal PMF $P_K(k)$ as a function of $k$. Provide the answer only for the case when $k$ is an even number.

I've already worked out that $P_{N,K}(n,k)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}$ (which is marked as correct) from $P_{K|N}(k|n)=\frac{P_{K,N}(k,n)}{P_N(n)}$, where $P_{K|N}(k|n)=\frac{1}{2n}$ as per the description of the problem.

***The key to the solution (attached below) seems to be that $n$ must be at least $\frac{k}{2}$ and I don't understand where can we get that information.***

In particular, I don't get why for certain $n$ values the probability is zero. I am not entirely sure whether the 'non-zero probability' in the solution refers to $P_{N,K}(n,k)$, or $P_{K|N}(k|n)$. But neither seems to be non-zero (suppose $k=6$):

$$P_{N,K}(n=1,k=6)=(\frac{1}{2})^{1+2}=\frac{1}{8}$$
$$P_{K|N}(k=6|n=1)=\frac{1}{2n} \text{where $n=1$}=\frac{1}{2\times 1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

So neither seems to be non-zero; where did I go wrong?

(The first paragraph of a comment, as far as I can understand, seems to suggest that $k$ must be a subset of $n$; but again I don't see where he is coming from. This has been attached after the solution below)

---

[image]

---

Comment:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the domain of your joint probability mass function. Taking the domain of $(N,K)$ as $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^2$, the joint probability should be specified as

$$P(N=n,K=k)= {1 \over 2^{n+2}}{\bf 1}_{k\leq 2n}.$$

In terms of your example, while $N=1$ has nonzero probability, $N=1,K=6$ $\textit{jointly}$ has zero probability. You can check that the joint masses sum to 1:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(N=n,K=k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over 2^{n+2}}{\bf 1}_{k\leq 2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{2n} {1 \over 2^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2n\over  2^{n+2}}=1.$$

If you wish to write $$P(N=n,K=k)= {1 \over 2^{n+2}},$$ it is understood the implicit domain here of $(N,K)$ is $\{(n,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}^2|k\leq 2n\}.$

Comment: Note that ${\bf 1}_A$ is an indicator function; it take the value $1$ when $A$ holds and takes the value zero otherwise.